# How to check version of python package if no __version__ variable is set

Tags: python, pip, pyodbc

I am using `pyodbc` and I want to know the version of it that I am using.
Apparently I cannot use `pyodbc.__version__` because probably the variable is not set.

How else can I figure out the version of the package?

Comment: Sometimes differently named version methods exist. After importing the package, you can use `dir(<packagename>)` to see which methods are available (like `<packagename>.__version__`). Other common ones are `<packagename>.version` and `<packagename>.VERSION`. I think there is a PEP for this, but can't remember offhand and not every package adheres to it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It does have the version info, just use `.version`:

```
In [4]: pyodbc.version
Out[4]: '3.0.10'
```

The pip show command would also get it for you:

```
In [54]: pip.main(["show","pyodbc"])
---
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Name: pyodbc
Version: 3.0.10
Summary: DB API Module for ODBC
Home-page: http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc
Author: Michael Kleehammer
Author-email: michael@kleehammer.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: 
Classifiers:
  Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable
  Intended Audience :: Developers
  Intended Audience :: System Administrators
  License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License
  Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows
  Operating System :: POSIX
  Programming Language :: Python
  Programming Language :: Python :: 2
  Programming Language :: Python :: 3
  Topic :: Database
Out[54]: 0
```

You could redirect stdout and parse the output:

```
import pip
import sys

if sys.version_info.major >= 3:
    from io import StringIO
else:
    from StringIO import StringIO


def get_version(package):
    f = StringIO()
    sys.stdout = f
    pip.main(["show", package])
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
    return next((line.split(":", 1)[1].strip()
                 for line in f.getvalue().splitlines() if line.startswith("Version")), "No match")
```

But an easier way is to use `pkg_resources`, if you look at the source for [show](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/develop/pip/commands/show.py), you can see how it is gathered:

```
from pip._vendor import pkg_resources

def get_version(package):
    package = package.lower()
    return next((p.version for p in pkg_resources.working_set if p.project_name.lower() == package), "No match")
```

To use it just pass the package name:

```
In [57]: get_version("pyodbc")
Out[57]: '3.0.10'

In [58]: get_version("pandas")
Out[58]: '0.17.1'

In [59]: get_version("requests")
Out[59]: '2.9.1'

In [60]: get_version("foobar")
Out[60]: 'No match'
```

You can easily extend it to get different info using similar logic to the show command.

Comment: The `pkg_resources` approach is the correct generic approach.

Answer (score 3):

To get a short report about the module, including its version, run:

`pip show pyodbc`

in a command prompt (e.g. Windows `cmd`). This works even for modules without a __version__ attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this command (from terminal)

```
pip freeze | grep pyodbc
```

For installation of pip (debian, ubuntu):

```
apt-get install python-pip
```

Comment: And there was me thinking I had made a new discovery ;)

Comment: I am not sure which I answer I should accept, the seconds is more generic when it comes to linux users while the first solves the problem for everyone but it answers the question for the specific package only

Comment: the first answer of @Padraic is the best for your question. I didn't known it, because i don't use pyodbc. :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to **start** --> **cmd** --> **pip list**

It list's all the packages you installed with version