# Retrieving python module own version from setup.py

Tags: python, flask, distutils

I am writing Flask based module with standard setup.py in root directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name=modulename,
      version='0.2.16.dev0',
      description='...',
      author='...',
      ...
     )
```

I am willing to expose module version using Flask API. What is the correct way to access my own module version programmatically?

Thanks

**Update:**
I forgot to mention that the module is not necessary installed as a standard module and may not be available in PYTHONPATH. This is why this question is not like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283541/how-to-check-version-of-python-package-if-no-version-variable-is-set) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180543/how-to-check-version-of-python-modules)

Comment: Setting a version in some variable and passing that variable to setup() is not an option, because I am using release tool which automatically sets this version....

Answer (score 0):

Put version in `version.py` or `__version__.py` or such (inside the package) and import it both in `setup.py` and the application:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from mypackage.version import version

setup(…
      version=version,
      …
     )
```

If importing your package in `setup.py` causes unwanted side effects you can just read `mypackage/version.py` and parse it or `exec()` or import it alone (without the package) with the trick:

```
from imp import load_source
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

versionpath = join(abspath(dirname(__file__)), "mypackage", "__version__.py")
load_source("mapackage_version", versionpath)
from mapackage_version import version
```